# What is the difference between [dependencies] and [dev-dependencies]?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

In a Cargo.toml manifest, what is the difference between the two types of dependencies? It seems that the "dev" dependency is conditional / invoked at a certain time only.

If I include a crate under `[dev-dependencies]` and try to use it in my code, it gives me an error:

```toml
[package]
# ... snipped ...

[dependencies]
# no uuid here

[dev-dependencies]
uuid = "1.0.0"
```

```
use uuid::Uuid;

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `uuid`
 --> src/main.rs:1:5
  |
1 | use uuid::Uuid;
  |     ^^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `uuid`
```

But if I move it under `[dependency]`, then there is no error. If the "dev" dependencies aren't used in my code, where are they used?

Comment: from my experience, the crates in the `dev-` are only for use in examples and tests.

Comment: There are also `[build-dependencies]`. See [What are build-dependencies?](/q/72861807/2189130)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are dependencies that only get included / built for examples, tests, and benchmarks. They will *not* be included when you run a simple `cargo build`.

See [development dependencies](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#development-dependencies) in the Cargo Book.